# Find out what is causing UAC prompts when opening PowerPoint 2007 slides

Tags: uac, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

At some point, I installed some third-party PowerPoint toolbars of unknown provenance. I don't remember their names or manufacturers. Doing so was a mistake. I uninstalled them shortly after.

Ever since, PowerPoint has been throwing up a UAC prompt every time I open a slide deck.

What steps do I need to take to find out what files (or registry keys) are making PowerPoint think it needs admin access every time it opens?

I've tried searching for `com`, `powerpoint` and variations thereof in the registry, but I haven't found anything suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file properties for powerpoint.exe, open the Compatibility tab.  Check if it's set to always run as administrator.

It's possible the toolbar installer could have done something like this.  The toolbar probably runs in the same security context as PowerPoint and the toolbar vendor might have been too lazy to update their code for UAC.